# Import asset from JSON file

Tags: json, webpack

My webpack app currently loads `.json` files using the recommended `asset/resource` module.

However, my `.json` file references static assets:

```
{
    "name": "MyApp",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/assets/images/icon-192.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "purpose": "any maskable"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like those assets to be added to the dependency graph automatically, just like the `html-loader` does. Is there a loader that can do that for JSON, or am I stuck copying those assets with `copy-webpack-plugin`?

Comment: How did you get webpack to load json as `asset/resource`? I have `{test: /\.(ico|svg|png|ttf|json)$/, type: "asset/resource"}` in my webpack config but it still loads it as `asset/source`

Comment: I've got : `{ test: /\.(avif|jpeg|jpg|json|png|svg)$/, type: 'asset/resource' }`, though it's been a while now since I last touched this part of my app and can't remember if it worked the way I expected.